# Flutter Chat Reply to Message

Tags: flutter, listview, chat

I'm trying to build a Chat UI with ListView. My first version was a `ListView.build` that works fine.

I want to upgrade my chat view for "replyTo message" option (similar to whatsapp). This requires the user to be able to click the "replyTo" message and scroll backwards to the original message. The `ListView.build` does not allow to scroll up to a message that is outside the screen view (as it is not even built).

```
body: Column(
    children: [
    Expanded(
        child: EasyRefresh.custom(
        ...
        slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, index) {
                ChatMessage _currMsg = vm.chat[index]!;
                ...
                return Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                    ...
                    SwipeTo(
                        onRightSwipe: () {
                            setState(() {
                                isReplying = true;
                                replyMessage = _currMsg;
                            });
                        },
                        child: ShowMessage(
                            key: Key(_currMsg.id!),
                            msg: _currMsg,
                            myMessage: _currMsg.postById == vm.user!.uid,
                            onTapReply: (id) async {
                                final ctx = _itemKey.currentContext;
                                if (ctx != null)
                                    await Scrollable.ensureVisible(ctx);
                            },
                        ),
                    ),
                    ],
                );
                },
                childCount: vm.chat.length,
            ),
            ),
        ],
        ),
    ),
```

It seems like the only way is to build all the list items at first build itself.

My question is, is there a way I can retain the already built items, and only add new incoming items rather than rebuilding all items every time.

Thanks.

Comment: What state management library are you using? share the code

Comment: Using redux. Added the code for sliverList item generation.